# What are the advantages of a trie, what is the equation used to calculate the time it takes to get to the desired word?

Tags: data-structures, tree, computer-science

I am working on a search for the subject of Terry and I want to know the features, and method of calculating the complexity ,
Is it better or not, and what alternative options and why?

Comment: Had you searched a bit (which you should always do before asking a question on [so]), you should know the answers to most of these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Advantages are fast search and insert. Both are O(m) operations where m is the size of the word. Also contrary to a hash table, you can efficiently perform queries like "give me all strings that begin with a certain string". Biggest disvantage is it has a big memory footprint, especially if implemented inefficiently.